# Weird content spacing in subsection in multicolumn document

Tags: spacing, multicol, white-space

I'm trying to get rid of the white spacing in the left column (mainly the white spacing depicted with the blue lines) to move the subsection title 4.4 to the left bottom page - see problem sketch. I tried to use `\raggedbottom` and `\flushbottom` but I did not achieve my desired result.

[image: Problem Sketch]

My code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin={1.9cm, 1.9cm}]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.83cm}
\hyphenpenalty=10000

\begin{multicols*}{2}
        ...
        \section{Title}
                ...
                \subsection{4.3 Title}
                        [content] \smallbreak

                        \noident [content] \smallbreak

                        \begin{itemize}
                                \item [content]
                                \item [content]
                                \item [content]
                        \end{itemize}

                        \noident [content] \smallbreak

                        \noident [content] \smallbreak

                \subsection{4.4 Title}

                \subsection{4.5 Title}
                
                ...
\end{multicols*}
```

So, what can I do to limit the white spacing in the left column and move the 4.4 subsection to the left page? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code block is not useful, no one can run it to see the issue.  Please edit so that the image is produced by the code provided

Comment: why do you have `\smallbreak` forcing extra space if you do not want extra space? start by removing all  `\smallbreak`  and `\noindent`